# Can I make Helm automatically delete resources created by my Helm-created app?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an app which I'm deploying with Helm. Once deployed, the app itself sometimes creates other Kubernetes resources (like `Deployments` and `Services`) in the same namespace as the app. When I run `helm delete` on the Helm release, it deletes all the resources originally created by Helm, but it leaves the resources that were created by the app. I would like to clean up these resources as well and I'm wondering if I can make Helm do so automatically.

I've tried applying the recommended labels from [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/#labels-and-annotations) such as `app.kubernetes.io/managed-by` and `app.kubernetes.io/instance` to my new resources, but Helm still doesn't delete them.

I also looked in the Helm manual but I can't find any clarity about how Helm decides what resources it "owns" and can delete.

(I know that I can use a Helm `pre-delete` or `post-delete` hook for this, but it feels cleaner to get Helm's normal deletion process to do this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not 100% sure about your setup, however, If you are talking about CRD's and controllers, Kubernetes uses a concept called finalizers and ownerRefs, finalizers are akin to before deleteing a resource do X (https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/using-finalizers.html very good reference),

OwnerReferences essentially means that when I delete a resource anything that has that resource set as its owner will be deleted, I have set it in a custom controller but never tried manually setting it on the yaml (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#owners-and-dependents)

Comment: I think this mostly answers the question. However, I don't see any `finalizers` or `ownerReferences` on the resources created by Helm, so the question of how Helm itself manages deletion seems to still be open.

I noticed that there's a `ConfigMap` with label `OWNER=TILLER` and a bunch of encoded data in it, could this be how Helm stores a list of the resources it has created?

I'll mark the answer accepted since setting the `ownerReferences` manually sounds like it will work, but it would be great to get a little more information about how Helm does it.

Comment: helm stores all the resources in configmaps, it is how it knows what chart has what resources, so when you delete a chart I would think technically it would find the configmap for that and delete all the resources. But if your app is actually creating the resources it would not be in this configmap. So I would suggest you app sets the ownerRefs of the resources it creates to itself, so when the app is deleted then Kubernetes will delete the resources your app has created

Comment: Minor update: Helm 2 stored app information in ConfigMaps, Helm 3 uses Secrets instead. Otherwise, I 100% agree on using `ownerReferences` when you create your own resource and want them to be deleted with a parent resource. Note that you can put *multiple* `ownerReferences`, in which case they must all be deleted for the resource to be garbage collected.